# Delphi XE3 Bluetooth how?

Tags: delphi, bluetooth, vcl, delphi-xe3

Hey guys i have a problem I've been searing for a way to get Delphi to connect to a Bluetooth device but with no luck i found components "Wireless Communication Library VCL Edition" but the are not free and the demo didn't work for me well so I'm wondering is there any other solution i might use? i need to be able to send commands to the device via Bluetooth get data from it etc.. all the standard  Bluetooth functions

IDE: Delphi XE3

I'm open to all ideas it can be a DLL library or a .pas

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: David Heffernan  its not a duplicate because his sittuation doesnt fit me :)

Comment: In what way does that question differ from your question?

Comment: As i sead i would prefer a vcl component in that answer they are giving a library that's written on indy i tried it and i couldent list any devices with it nor connect to them

Comment: The answers don't matter. It's whether or not the question asks the same as the other question that determines whether or not it's a dupe. And "I'm open to all ideas" contradicts "It has to be VCL".

Comment: I tried all the solutions here and neither fitted me so im asking the question i know the rules and that they dont allow duplicates but this is not a duplicate :-)

Comment: AirWolf: If your question isn't a dupe then it's uselessly vague. Do you want to connect to a bluetooth keyboard? A bluetooth handsfree device? A cell phone? If so, what do you want to do? Serial port emulation over bluetooth? File transfer? HID (keyboard)? What? The answer is probably the same; There ain't no bluetooth libraries for Delphi. And "All the standard functions" is far too vague.